# Code review: Determining whether a folder exists, given the full file path?

Tags: .net, vb.net, path-manipulation

With a function being passed a full path to a file, such as `C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\someXML.xml`, determine whether the folder exists.  Is there a smarter/better/more elegant way of doing this?  Here is my implementation:

```
Private Function FolderExists(ByVal fullPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim folders() As String = fullPath.Split("\")
    Dim folderPath As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To folders.Length - 2 'subtract 2 to avoid appending the filename.
        folderPath += folders(i) + "\"
    Next
    Dim f As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
    Return f.Exists
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) instead, it accepts a full path.

EDIT: Sorry, calling your directory variable `f` confused me.... I trust you can translate the following C# code:-

```
 return Directory.Exists( Path.GetDirectoryName( fullPath ) );
```

The [.NET BCL ARM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321154894) has decent coverage of this stuff, though I'm sure there's a better reference out there. The `System.IO.Path` and `Environment` docs would probably be just fine.

Comment: I should have known there'd be an API call built in just for this :) Thanks!

Comment: To translate the C# code, just remove the semicolon. C# is so wordy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(VS.71).aspx))

```
Private Function FolderExists(ByVal fullPath As String) As Boolean
  return (File.exists(fullPath)
          And (File.GetAttributes(fullPath) And FileAttributes.Directory))
End Function
```

Comment: -1: He's got a full path including filename and needs to split it to determine if the **directory** exists and was lookign for a neat way to do that